# Getting null value for Azure blob last modified property

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting ***null*** when I'm trying to fetch LastModified property of Azure Blob, below is the snippet for the same.

> ```
> CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("account");
> CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
> CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("folder");
> var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
> foreach (var blob in blobs)
> {
> CloudBlockBlob blockBlob =container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.ToString());
> var timemodified = blockBlob.Properties.LastModified;
> }
> ```

value fetched in *blob* above is not a CloudBlobDirectory.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason you're getting this behavior is because when you execute following line of code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.ToString());
```

It essentially creates a new instance of `CloudBlockBlob` object and it's properties are initialized to the default value. You would need to call `FetchAttributes` method on this to fill the properties.

Also, when you list the blobs the properties of the blob are fetched as well. So you need not create a new instance of `CloudBlockBlob`. Simply use the `blob` object you got as listing result and use the properties from there. So your code would be:

```
        foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            var timemodified = blob.Properties.LastModified;
        }
```

Comment: Getting below exception on blockBlob.FetchAttributes()

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: Instead of using `blob.ToString()`, find out blob's name and use that. Assuming all your blobs are of type `BlockBlob`, you could do something like `container.GetBlockBlobReference((blob as CloudBlockBlob).Name)`. **However, please note that when you call `FetchAttributes` you're making a request to Azure storage to get the information which is already there in your `blob` object.**

Comment: Although, I'm uncertain of the blob type as it could be any CloubBlockBlob or CloudBlobDirectory. That i can handle it in my code thanks for the help.

Cheers :)

Comment: If all you want is the list of blob (and make sure you don't get `CloudBlobDirectory`), you can simply do `var blobs = container.ListBlobs(null, true)`. This will ensure that you don't get back any directories when listing blobs.

Comment: But this would not get me blobs inside the child BlobDirectory

Comment: That's correct. This will give you a list of all the blobs in all the directories.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use a newer version of `CloudBlockBlob` and `FetchAttributes` does not exist – use `DownloadAttributes` instead.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.ToString());
blockBlob.DownloadAttributes();
var timemodified = blockBlob.Properties.LastModified;
```