# null value for Azure File Share property LastModified

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

```
  // Get list of all files/directories on the file share 
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);

            var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));

            var test = sourceName.Properties.LastModified;
```

But `sourceName.Properties.LastModified is null`

even `fileShare.Properties.LastModified is null`

I'm getting null when I'm trying to fetch LastModified property of Azure File Share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is every time you call `GetRootDirectoryReference()` you create a new instance of `FileItem`, causing in it's properties to be initialized to it's default value, just the same behavior as when using `GetBlockBlobReference()`.

What you need to do is to call `FetchAttributes` on this in order to fill all the properties.

Note that when the properties are fetched you do not need to create a new instance of your object.

you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281329/getting-null-value-for-azure-blob-last-modified-property) that references blobs but is concerning your error as well.

---

An example as you requested would be:

```
public static void ListContainerMetadataAsync(CloudBlobContainer container)
{
    // Fetch container attributes in order to populate the container's 
       properties and metadata.
     container.FetchAttributes();

    // Enumerate the container's metadata.
    Console.WriteLine("Container metadata:");
    foreach (var metadataItem in container.Metadata)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tKey: {0}", metadataItem.Key);
        Console.WriteLine("\tValue: {0}", metadataItem.Value);
    }
}
```

You can read more at [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata).

Comment: great thanks :)
can i use below query for getting sub folder last updated file as well ? 
var latest = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories()
   .OfType<CloudFileShare>()
   .OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified)
   .ToList()
   .First();

I have separate question you can help i guess pls help me _
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035111/how-do-we-track-azure-file-storage-folder-is-updated-or-not

Comment: Yes, I believe you can and I'll do my best to assist :)

Comment: thanks a lot 
ohh i just noticed that , i have uploaded one new file just now into that folder but still LastModified is old date , it means LastModified is separate for that folder and file :O what to do now ?

Comment: I want to check whether any new file is updated into any sub-fodler of main folder or not within 24hr.

Comment: can we use any linq query like i mentioned into question ?

Comment: I tried linq query i posted in question but getting error - Sequence contains no elements'